# How to handle many integers/strings in SQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, integer

I want to create a table that can handle (40 or so) integers and about as many strings.  Whats the bst approach to this (yes I don't know much about SQL but I'm trying) TYIA -Roland

Comment: What does 40 mean? Is it rows or columns?

Comment: I am not sure which is best I just need to store 40 or so integers for retrieval later.  Also there will be several sets of integers and strings of varying number

Comment: If you can put all your ints together to prevent loss of space due to padding.  Other than that, go for it.  You may need to look into normalizing your table eventually, or possibly moving less used data to another table with a FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with the following columns:
- integer column 
- string column.

You can add also a primary key, autoincrement, autofill (if possible, if not you will have to fill it yourself)

Comment: Great just what I needed.  Sorry for the newb question but I read an SQL book it was just a while ago and I haven't had much practice